# Ubuntu 12.04 Wireless problem in hp pavilion g6

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, hp, function-keys

This is the first time i use a linux distribution and i have a problem. I installed ubuntu without any problems but i can not connect networks. I simply can not turn on wifi because function keys do not work anymore. I am a beginner but, i think it can be a result of not having a driver for wireless, but i do not know how to find or install linux drivers.I do not have a lot of knowledge about linux so please try to be simple as possible. Thanks.

Edit: Now i am able to use function keys but still i can not turn on the wifi.
Edit 2: my wireless card is broadcom bcm4313 802.11b/g/n

Comment: Can you tell the wireless card name

Comment: How can i learn that?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280. That funny pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given wireless card name.

I am giving you example with Intel card

I will revise the answer once you give exact name. If you cannot find the name the safe trick can be used which i mentioned in additional shortcut below.

Making Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 work in Ubuntu or other Linux.

Before that some quick simple summary how it works.

The Linux drivers are part of the upstream Linux kernel. But some devices needs additional firmware to tell kernel what device is all about and how to operate it.

So we need to download the firmware from Intel website and place in

/lib/firmware of the system , simple

So head to

http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm

Download the tar related to kernel you have and device you have
Extract it
Place it in /lib/firmware

Reboot your machine

Done!!

Additional notes.

All of these are also part of Linux community code

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/

In Ubuntu, firmware comes from one of the following sources:

```
The linux-image package (which contains the Linux kernel and licensed firmware)
The linux-firmware package (which contains other licensed firmware)
The linux-firmware-nonfree package in multiverse (which contains firmware that are missing redistribution licenses)
A separate driver package
Elsewhere (driver CD, email attachment, website)
```

The ideal scenario would have been some one back porting the latest firmeware in linux-firmware for saucy. But this not been done so we can just manually
drop the file.

A additional shortcut you can follow is just download Trusty (14.04) deb file and install it. The trusty already has the firmware for it.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/linux-firmware/download

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Firmware